# collectionview in tableview fourth not work (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

It does not work normally from the fourth

First page text 0

Second page text 1

Third page text 2

fourth page text 0

The first page value is displayed on the fourth page.

collection view horizontal paging

[This is how my collection view looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF4ZM.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "TestCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TestCollectionCell")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionCell
        cell.selectRow = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let cvRect = collectionView.frame
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: cvRect.height)
    }
}
```

```
class TestCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var selectRow = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell.init()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(selectRow)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: your Quesation not clear . what does not working ?

Comment: The fourth page text 3 should be printed, but 0 is printed

Comment: Try resetting content of cell by using `prepareForReuse`